# Finding radius for inscribed scalene triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, triangles

We have length of three sides which are $5,6,7$. How can the radius be found? Is there any easy way to find that? If the angles were there, it would be found from, 
$$ r = c \cdot\frac{sin\frac{ A}{2} \cdot sin\frac{B}{2}}{cos \frac{C}{2}} $$

I can't find a simple way for it.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forumla is $$R = {abc\over 4A}$$

where $A = \sqrt{s(s-a)(s-b)(s-b)}$ is area of triangle and $s$ is half of a perimeter of triangle.

Comment: is it well-known formula or did you find it?

Comment: First one..........

Comment: The first formula which relates the area, radius and side lengths of a triangle inscribed in a circle can be found here: http://www.mathcaptain.com/geometry/inscribed-triangle.html 
and Heron's Formula can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula